# AzureAD Powershell copy one user group memberships to another user

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

So the issue is i am fully on AzureAD, no on-prem server. I am trying to make a script to copy one user group membership's to another user where all i need to input are the users email addresses.
I have been able to achieve this by using the user's objectId's but i really do not want to go looking for the ObjectId's if that makes sense.

The script i have written is below:

```
# import the Azure Active Directory module in order to be able to use Get-AzureADUserMembership and Add-AzureADGroupMember cmdlet
import-Module AzureAD

Connect-AzureAD

# enter login name of the first user
$user1 = Read-host "Enter username to copy from: " 

# enter login name of the second user
$user2  = Read-host "Enter username to copy to: " 

# Get ObjectId based on username of user to copy from and user to copy to
$user1ObjId = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user1
$user2ObjId = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user2

# Show List of all the groups to be copied
Write-Host "\-- Groups available to copy from" $user1 to $user2 "--\" -ForegroundColor Yellow
ForEach-Object{
    Write-Host "[ ] - List AD UserMembership that $user1 has " -ForegroundColor Blue
Get-AzureADUserMembership  -ObjectId $user1 | Select DisplayName
     }

# copy-paste process
Write-Host "[!] - Adding" $user2 "to the same groups" $user1 " has " "..." -ForegroundColor Yellow -nonewline
Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $user1ObjId |foreach { Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $_.ObjectId -RefObjectId $User2ObjId }
```

The script successfully saves the ObjectId for each user in the variables $user1ObjId and $user2ObjId, i am also able to list the groups that need to be copied over.
However i run into a problem where the Get cmdlets seems to be unable to bind the variables that contain the ObjectId.

I don't know if this makes sense to anyone what i am trying to explain or achieve?

Here is the error snip
[error snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZnhx.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i was able to work with a friend to get this resolved and i thought to share it here as well since i have not really seen any online documentation or solution to using AzureAD cmdlets to copy one user group membership to another user.

Here is the script that works:

```
# import the Azure Active Directory module in order to be able to use Get-AzureADUserMembership and Add-AzureADGroupMember cmdlet
import-Module AzureAD

Connect-AzureAD

# enter login name of the first user
$user1 = Read-host "Enter username to copy from: "

# enter login name of the second user
$user2  = Read-host "Enter username to copy to: " 

# Get ObjectId based on username of user to copy from and user to copy to
$user1Obj = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user1
$user2Obj = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user2


$membershipGroups = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $user1Obj.ObjectId

Write-Host "\-- Groups available to copy from" $user1 to $user2 "--\" -ForegroundColor Yellow

foreach($group in $membershipGroups) {
Write-Host $group.DisplayName
Write-Host "[!] - Adding" $user2Obj.UserPrincipalName " to " $group.DisplayName "... " -ForegroundColor Yellow -nonewline
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -RefObjectId $user2Obj.ObjectId
Write-Host "Done"
}
```

I hope this makes someone's life a little easier :)

Comment: This was a lifesaver tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the same problem. But a little differently. I made the script easy to use for my colleagues. But if it is of use to anyone that would be great.

This script gets all of the users in a tenant. You pick the example user. Next the target user. All groups of the example will be added to the ragetuser. Since the Get-AzureADUserMembership cmdlet would also try to add the 'roles' I remove the roles.

```
#Connect to tenant
Connect-AzAccount

#Get all users's UPN and OnjectID
$users = Get-AzureADUser | Select-Object UserPrincipalName, ObjectID

# Choose the example user
$userA = $users | Out-GridView -Title "Select Example User" -PassThru

# Choose Target user
$userB = $users | Out-GridView -Title "Select Target User" -PassThru
 
# List of all groups of Example user
$groups = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectID $userA.ObjectId | Where-Object ObjectType -EQ group

# Add Target user to groups from example user
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    try{
        Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectID $group.ObjectId -RefObjectId $userB.ObjectId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    catch{
        if($_.exception.message -like "*references already exist*"){
            Write-Host "$($group.DisplayName) Has already been added to $($userB.UserPrincipalName)"
        }
    }
}
```